# breaking up an API connection call into functions Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, function, methods

This most likely a very trivial questions but I have a connection set up to an API in order to retrieve information.  Right now I have everything setup in viewDidLoad.  I know there is a more efficient way to place this information for later access by the user but I am too inexperienced in Objective-C to know how to do it.  Here is how I have it all laid out at the moment.

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.myurl.com"]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSData *myResponse = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myResponse encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    SBJsonParser *myParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSArray *myData = [parser objectWithString:myString error:nil];
```

Comment: This question is too open ended. Would you like to execute it later based on a user action, a time delay, or just later in the view controller life cycle?

Comment: I am going to need to use the connection on 2 different pages.  So when the user changes pages it will have the same connection.  Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: So you would like to make a connection in the background and have it keep running while you go through "x" number of pages? Just to be clear so I can give you the right answer. Do you want it to notify you when it completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)loadAndParseURL:(NSString *)URLString
             completion:(void (^)(NSArray *data))completion {

    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      NSData *myResponse = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];

      NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myResponse encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      SBJsonParser *myParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

      NSArray *myData = [parser objectWithString:myString error:nil];
      completion(myData);
    });
}
```

`completion` is a block (anonymous function pointer), which accepts an array as parameter and executes customized code blocks. The block holds the value of local variables, aka the 'environment', and evaluates its content at the time of execution(, usually with delay of some kind), in this example, after `myData` is parsed from `myString`. `dispatch_async` puts the anonymous block that sends the request and does other stuff onto a background queue (in a background thread, of course). So the calling to this method is returned before the response is even received, and you should arrange anything after within the `completion` block.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  What does the completion(myData) do?

Answer (score 0):

If spinning it off into a thread is what you are looking for I would use sendAsynchronousRequest

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
   NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   SBJsonParser *myParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSArray *myData = [parser objectWithString:myString error:nil];

   // Do what you want with the response and subscribe 
   //anywhere in your code to get notified when it completed.
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
          postNotificationName:@"NotifyMeWhenDone" 
                        object:self];

}];
```